# Is it possible to get the filters applied on a particular dimension?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

Is it possible to get the filters applied on a particular dimension? I need to obtain all filters applied on a group of dc.js charts on click of a button.

Answer (score 10):

I did something similar. 
However instead of using a button click I was getting the values each time the chart was filtered by attaching a renderlet.

The function your looking for is *filters()*

i.e

```
  yourChart.renderlet(function(chart) {
            dc.events.trigger(function() {
                console.log(yourChart.filters())
            });
        })
```

This will log the filters applied to the dimension given to the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of selected filters using the chart.filterPrinter() function which returns a function that returns a string version of the selected filters. The following code segment would return the string version of the currently selected filters for a chart.

```
chart.filterPrinter()(chart.filters())
```

You can even provide your own filterPrinter function for customization.

You can define on('filtered' function that is fired each time a filter value changes on a chart. This function receives the chart as the first argument, and current filter selection/un-selection as the second argument. But, you can get the full list of current selected filters using chart.filters() function.

```
myChart.on('filtered', function(chart, filter) {
    var sel = chart.filterPrinter()(chart.filters());
    console.log('Selected Filters are: ' + sel);
});
```